# Translating latinic to Cyrillic with html tags inside text?

Tags: php

A friend of mine asked me how can he translate text inside textarea from latinic to Cyrillic but to avoid xss danger.

```
Example : <b>bold</b> to <б>болд</б>
```

He translates text bold but text inside <> remains the same so it could be used for xss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Unicode values do not overlap.

Do a simple `switch` and map all the characters.

Or use an array.